# HashMap is empty after deserialization with Jersey and Jackson

Tags: hashmap, jersey, jackson

I have a REST web service using Jersey 1.17.1 and Jackson 1.9.2.

The API looks like this:

```java
public class PlayerRequest {
    private String language;
    private String playerId;
    private Map<String, String> params;
}
```

When this service is called by other component, the `params` map is received empty:

```
PlayerRequest [language=null, playerId=100036343, params={}]
```

Original request from other component:

```
PlayerRequest [language=null, playerId=100036343, params={context=mobile, countrycode=SE, partnerskin=8, locale=en_GB, ipaddress=62.209.186.13}]
```

Why is the HashMap empty after the deserialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by implementing and adaptor(javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter) and annotated the map in api with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter

Answer (score 0):

In your `PlayerRequest` class, create a method annotated with [`@JsonAnySetter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonAnySetter.html), as following:

```java
@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String key, String value) {
    params.put(key, value);
}
```

This method works as a *fallback handler* for all unrecognized properties found in the JSON content.

---

To use the above mentioned approach, ensure the `params` field is being initialized:

```java
private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

So, your `PlayerRequest` class would be like:

```java
public class PlayerRequest {

    private String language;
    private String playerId;
    private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public PlayerRequest() { }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(String playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String key, String value) {
        params.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I initialised it in the set method:
@JsonAnySetter
 public void set(String key, String value) {
  if (params == null) {
   params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  }
  params.put(key, value);
 }

Comment: @mickygo And what was the result?

Comment: same, empty params{}